# iOS : Collection view doesn't show

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uicollectionview

I have a collection view in my app, I want it to contain a custom cells. I've created a custom cell view xib file. Then I use it in my data source method :

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 OtherCustomersCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:OTHER_CUSTOMERS_CELL_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];

  if(cell == nil){
      NSArray *nsObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OtherCustomersCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    for(id obj in nsObjects)
        if([obj isKindOfClass:[OtherCustomersCell class]])
            cell = (OtherCustomersCell*) obj;
}
[cell.name setText:@"AAAA BBBBB"];

return cell;
}
```

But when I run the app, there is just a black rectangular where the collection view should be (at the bottom under the table view):

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you registered it?

Comment: @sanjitshaw  Are you asking about the collection view? I've added it through my storyboard file. Or the custom cell? than no, but I'm doing the same process with my table view and it works fine (as you can see)

Comment: I've posted an answer check that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collection views work differently than table views in that you don't have to create a cell if one can't be dequeued.

Instead, you have to register the nib for the cell first:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...

    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"OtherCustomersCell" bundle:nil];
    [collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:OTHER_CUSTOMERS_CELL_IDENTIFIER];
}
```

You can then dequeue the cell and it will be created automatically for you if necessary:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    OtherCustomersCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:OTHER_CUSTOMERS_CELL_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath]; // cell won't be nil, it's created for you if necessary!
    [cell.name setText:@"AAAA BBBBB"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer!

Comment: along those lines, it should be:


UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"OtherCustomersCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.photoGridView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:OTHER_CUSTOMERS_CELL_IDENTIFIER];

Answer (score 2):

You have to register `UICollectionView` instance in the following way in viewdidload  then you can use this.

```
[self.photoListView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"UIcollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Identifier"];
```